# Which local Flutter database can be easily synched with Firebase but also exist fully independently (without ever connecting to Firebase)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Question:**
I considered using SQLite for the local database and making a link with Firebase but I read in similar threads that is quite complex as firebase is NoSQL. Does anyone know what is the easiest way to have a local database that can exist for years without Firestore, then be plugged into it for a few months, and then unplugged again for months?

**Details:**

I want to have an app that exists in two forms:

**A: Basic one**
User can store their data only in the local database in the app, with no cloud database connection. This option never connects to Firebase and does not have a Firebase authentication user.

**B: Premium**
Users can store data locally and online (cloud/Firebase). The changes in the app are stored in the Firebase database (and locally).

The Basic user can decide to go Premium and, in this case, they will get a Firebase user to auth ID, and all their previous ‘Basic’ data will be copied to Firebase and updated from now on locally and in Firebase.

The ‘Premium’ user can become ‘Basic’ – the connection with Firebase will stop from now on, and the user will only update local data, starting with the latest copy of local data synced from Firebase just before the disconnection from Firebase.

(Maybe Firebase is not the best option? What else then?)
(Somebody somewhere wrote about using ‘JSON’ database to have a format similar to Firebase, but I have found no info about using JSON for ‘database’ in Flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I considered using SQLite for the local database and making a link with Firebase but I read in similar threads that is quite complex as Firebase is NoSQL.

Yes, you can use a local database like [SQLite](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) and later keep it in sync with a cloud-hosted database like [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). Regarding complexity, as soon as you learn the basics, it won't be so complex anymore.

Furthermore, both "Basic one" and "Premium" features can be implemented using SQLite and Firebase.

> Maybe Firebase is not the best option?

IMHO, it is the best option for your particular use case.

> What else then?

You can also take a look at the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), it's the other NoSQL cloud-hosted real-time database from Firebase.

Comment: Hey, konstanty. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?